# Any suggestions to help someone experiencing joint pain after giving up dairy products?

Tags: veganism, health

My wife is a long time Vegetarian, and recently decided to move to a Vegan diet. She's been very successful so far, and feels great in general. However, over the past few weeks she has been experiencing more joint pain after her runs, and occasional muscle aches in the morning when she wakes up. We've read a lot online about alleged "dairy withdrawal" and related topics, but nothing seems to be fact-based, it is all hyperbolic, and vague. We are both committed Vegans and don't need to be convinced of the evils of the dairy industry, so we'd like some solid suggestions that are helpful without all the hyperbole.

Comment: Has she consulted with a doctor about this?

Comment: She has, but it was not particularly helpful. They were tentatively supportive of the change in diet, but cautioned about calcium and protein, the usual 'boogeymen' of Vegan diets everywhere. She has an appointment with her CDE soon (she's a Type 1 Diabetic) and is hoping to get some feedback. For now it is more of a search to filter out the alarmist stuff and see if anyone has gone through this (I've been Vegan for a long time and don't remember experiencing it)

Comment: Finding out about low calcium and vitamin D levels is a simple blood test she could take, no vague warnings by her doctor necessary.

Comment: @Turion Maybe [that should be the answer to this question](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/please-do-not-answer-in-the-comments)?

Comment: @Nic, no, I was just responding to the previous comments. Without a blood test, we can't say whether it's calcium or Vitamin D deficiency, and without that information, no good answer is possible.

Comment: StackExchange sites cannot be a source of medical diagnoses; a medical professional needs to be consulted about problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of lack of calcium.

So try calcium rich foods.

I found a [link](https://draxe.com/top-10-calcium-rich-foods/) and added an image below of calcium rich foods from the site (this image contains non-vegetarian as well as non-vegan products, so just avoid those).

[image]

Comment: Bioavailability of calcium from dairy is widely accepted as controversial.

Comment: +1 I was not aware Kale contained that much calcium.